# Possible to autoscale to a small instance like F2 from F4 in Google App Engine?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

In my app.yaml for Google App Engine I am using instance class as F4.

```
instance_class: f4
```

And when GAE autoscales, is it possible for GAE to spin up instance F2 instead of F4.

Can we make some setting in app.yaml to do so ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make use of the App Engine Admin API to change that value, as the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/admin-api/reference/rest/v1/apps.services.versions#Version.FIELDS.instance_class) of the API shows. There is a field, named `instanceClass` you can use to change the type of the instance that is serving your application.

With that, you won't even need to redeploy your application as you can simply [patch it](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/admin-api/reference/rest/v1/apps.services.versions/patch) on the fly.

Other than that, you won't be able to achieve that behavior using the `app.yaml` without redeploying the whole app.

If your goal is to downscale the `instance_class` during hours with less workload, you can make use of [Cloud Scheduler](https://cloud.google.com/scheduler/docs/creating) to make a call to the App Engine Admin API and have this automated.